# htaccess rewrite one directory and all requests to that directory to a different directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to route any request for example.com/forum/ to the directory /simplemachines/simplemachines/ while keeping the user's url shown as /forum/

So even if an image is requested from a sub folder like:

```
example.com/forum/theme/logos/logo_sml.png
```

the request should be served from the simplemachines directories without changing the url for the user, so the logo request would be mapped to:

```
example.com/simplemachines/simplemachines/theme/logos/logo_sml.png
```

I've done a good bit of googling and trying different solutions and while I can get the base /forum/ url pointed to the subdirectory, any requests for files or other content gives me a 404.

Here is the latest iteration of what I've tried in my htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^forum/(.*)$ /simplemachines/simplemachines/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Also, this is to route requests to the forum away from the wordpress install and /forum is not an existing directory.

All together, my current htaccess file with the wordpress rules in place looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

# forums
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^forum/(.*)$ /simplemachines/simplemachines/$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Is there a way to do what I'm looking to do?

Comment: No, forum is not a real directory. Requests for /forum need to be handled separately from wordpress too, which I'm going to add to my question above

Comment: With WP you have to use their rewrite API for this. https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API

Comment: Even with the wordpress rules removed from the htaccess file,  the rewriting for the forum url doesn't work. I'd still like to get that working as it sits outside of wordpress.

Comment: That caused /forum/  to be redirected and show the /simplemachines/simplemachines/ in the url to the user. The request for the image did not work and did not redirect. Manually replacing the /forum/ in the image's url with the simplemachines directories does show the image so I know that the image path is correct.

Comment: That is the problem with frameworks. They do so many things via plugins, hooks etc under the cover